# Выделение общих зависимостей на уровень выше

Tags: javascript, node.js

Проект с примерно такой структурой

```
root-dir/
  package.json
  src/
    module-A/
      webpack.config.js
      package.json
    module-B/
      webpack.config.js
      package.json
```

`module-A` и `module-B` требуют одни и те же зависимости (в моем случае это `react, redux, babel, webpack`...)

Хотелось бы объявить все эти общие зависимости на уровень выше в `root-dir/package.json` и сделать так что они были доступны и в `module-A` и в `module-B`

Т.е. если я запускаю `yarn webpack` из `module-A` запускался `webpack` с конфигом который лежит в `src/module-A`.

Возможно ли это и если да то как реализуется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node style module resolution так и работает - ищется требуемый пакет всякий раз на уровень выше, если не находится на текущем уровне.

у webpack есть аргумент --config для уточнения адреса/имени файла конфига

Собственно в чём возникает проблема?

П.С. многие много-пакетные (babel, apollo и другие) репозитории используют lerna, может она как-то поможет

Comment: Lerna это решение моей проблемы